# subprocess.run returns error when triggered using Gitlab CI

Tags: python, subprocess, gitlab-ci

I'm using Python subprocess.run() to execute a Powershell script.
When I ran this program locally, everything works fine, but when I'm using Gitlab CI to trigger the program, I'm getting back:
'powershell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
subprocess.run(f'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "prog.ps1 arg1 arg2 arg3"',shell = True,
                        capture_output = True,text = True)
```

Comment: If you installed your runner as a service, make sure you have configured the service user's `PATH` environment variable (or set this in your CICD variables). Alternatively, try using the absolute path to `powershell.exe`